# Is there a way to open a .wmf file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wmf

Is there any support or library in python for opening ".wmf" format files and converting them into arrays for further operations?

Comment: You may use libwmf to convert wmf to SVG and then pyrsvg to convert to PNG

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I call libwmf via python? I am not seeing any direct way to do it. Can you shed some light on it, please?

Comment: libwmf can't be found. I will let you know if i can find it

Comment: In the mean time, try using PIL like this `from PIL import Image

Image.open("xxx.wmf").save("xxx.png")` To convert the file to PNG then it can be loaded it to array easily

Comment: I have tried the PIL approach but it gives me "OSError: cannot find loader for this WMF file". Is it working for you?

Comment: I have done similar in the past. I don't have environment to check now

Comment: I followed a tutorial given  [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_wmf-pil.html). Even this tutorial was not working.

Comment: Check the answer here, it is one of the possibilities
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392370/download-wmf-from-pptx-and-decode-to-jpeg

Answer (score 2):

PIL only has wmf support on Windows

Comment: Then how to handle this thing in a Linux machine?